# Measure HTTP and HTTPS response time via Proxy using Java 7

Tags: java, http, https, proxy

I am looking to build a network test tool where I can measure a site http and https response time via multiple proxies utilizing java 7. Someone might look at this question and think this question might be duplicate as I have seen many answers related to http subject. But my question is related to Java 7, HTTP and HTTPS.

So is it possible and how to go about implementing it?

Answer (score 0):

As far as my knowledge there was never a in-built support from Java to measure HTTP or HTTPS connections.

All we have to do is `System.currentTimeMillis()` or `System.nanoTime()` at the beginning and end of the call and find the difference.

Other way is enable the debug by `-Djavax.net.debug=all` and analyze the time (may not be realistic because of debug on).